# Open Notepad++ with a folder as a project

Tags: windows, command-line, notepad++

I am looking for a way to open notepad++ in a folder (using `cmd`) and auto-load this folder as a project or open it with light explorer plugin. Say I go to `D:/foo/bar` in cmd and want to run something like `npp .` to do it. Or when I am somewhere else I'd do `npp D:/foo/bar`

Hope it's clear enough. I think OS X' TextMate has something like `mate .`

Answer (score 2):

You try this way:-

```
notepad++.exe -multiInst YourDirectorypath
```

But this will load all files under this directory

Go through this **[Notepad++ Commands](http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/commands)** and **[Notepad++ Command Line](http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/command-line)** documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's still not what I was looking for. This feature is so important for me (often switching projects), that I moved to Sublime Text 2...